# Using redis pub-sub for key expiry

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, node-redis, redistributable

I have a requirement where i am pushing my keys to redis with some expiration time. Also have a subscriber for listening key expiration events and then have a callback to my other system which can perform some business rules on it. Is it a good design to have faith in redis pub-sub for this usecase? 
Average TTL for keys will be in range ~15 minutes.

Using other design will make me having a scheduler/cron(every minute) or some polling system.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have been using Redis pub/sub for exactly the same use case in production and has been working quite well for me without any issues.

Comment: Thanks Alok, can you help with 1 more thing - in production, i will have this setup in more than 1 machine where subscriber will run in all these machines. So what could be the best way to handle the same expiration event so that i do not callback other system more than for key expiration?

Comment: Do you mean a master slave setup in production or a cluster. In case of a cluster, it won't be an issue since any particular key would be stored only on a single instance. I case of master/slave setup, you can put the subscriber to listen to events only from master instances.

Comment: No, i meant the subscriber will be in a java application which will subscribe to redis master expiry events. Now this application will be deployed in multiple machines, so expiry events will come to all subscribed machines(as all machines will have same packaging and same subscriber code). On receiving this event, i will have a callback to other systems, so how can i handle this case where i don't send callback from all machines as it will be repetition of expiry events. 1 way is to deploy the subscriber application only in 1 machine. But what could be the best way?

Comment: Redis does not have shared subscriptions. You would have to run the Java application on a single instance. You can use Kafka as buffer between your Java application and other systems to handle spikes in load.